# Programmatically instantiate custom view controller and getting the subviews by tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I have three view controllers each under the same custom view controller class, and a page view controller. I want to be able to reuse these three view controllers but with different content on their subviews. However, when I try to instantiate one of these view controllers from the page view controller using `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier]`, with a method to find the subview by tag right after, the subview returned is null. Is there some way I can get the subview by tag right after instantiating the view controller programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view controller's views don't get created until it is about to be displayed. They won't be created after the call to `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`

You should put code that accesses the view controllers views in `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, or `viewDidAppear`.

You should not try to manipulate a view controller's views from an outside object. That violates the principle of encapsulation, an important principle of object-oriented design. (It also often doesn't work, as you found out.)

If you need do things to the views programmatically you should add one or more public methods to the view controller and call those methods to ask the view controller to make adjustments to its views.

Comment: I tried placing the code in the three view methods but it only changes the subview when, like you said, the view is about to be displayed which is not what I am looking for since I want the information to be on the view already. Is there no way I can make adjustments to these subViews before the view is displayed?

Comment: viewDidLoad is called right after a view controller's views are created **but before they are displayed**. That is the place to do one-time setup when a view controller loads it's views.

Comment: It seems to be different for a scrolling pageview since my subviews didn't change until I completely swiped to the view when using viewDidLoad. I ended up using viewDidLayoutSubviews which is what I needed. Thanks for the help